# Preact Router - SEO route text

Tags: preact

I've looked through the documentation but can't seem to find any reference to doing this, which seems like a pretty common use case.

https://github.com/developit/preact-router

I'm trying to achieve something this:
`domain.com/(:slug)-group` (brackets added for illustration only)

Where `slug` is the value I need, and `-group` is a generic string applied to urls purely for the sake of SEO.

How can I dynamically differentiate between the slug and the generic text? I could simply strip `-group` out but there could be hundreds of strings like this.